# AlertDialog showing up in emulator but not in phone

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm a terrible programmer but have managed to pull togheter an app that are used by my coworkers to ease their daily work. I have now been asked to put in a Dialog-box. Like I always do I searched the internet long and hard and more or less stole a solution. Which I implemented with great success when trying the emulator. However when updating the app on my coworkers phone it didn't work - the app still works fine but no Dialog-box is shown.

My guess is that this as something to do with API-level of the devices. But according to my research AlertDialog has been a valid method for quite a while. I need the dialog-box to show at a phone with android version 4.1.2.

Below is my code, hopefully it is a simple mistake or someone can help me with another solution. I don't get any errors.

Big thanks in advance!

```
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    showUrl = "http://randomurl.php";
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Yes or No?").setPositiveButton("yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("no", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html  check here

Comment: I have visited and read that site a couple of times and I'm sorry but I fail to find the solution. Is is possible for you to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use right way to Display AlertDialog as per Developer site

Comment: Your show url is not showing anything,Moreover I checked your above code in my phone,AlerDialog is working fine.

Comment: The url was changed due to stupid NDAs. However big thanks for trying it out in your phone. It seem certain that the problem is with the version of android. Any alternative methods to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(RecordActivity.this);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("alert_message"));

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Click Here", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Intent i = new Intent(RecordActivity.this, PurchaseActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_ACTIVITY_PURCHASE);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume this should replace all of my code. However I can't get this to work, I get an error at R.string.click_here and R.string.cancel. Apperently this values can't be resolved.

Comment: Check my edited answer...
And give vote if you satisfied

Comment: Will be very satsified if you help me with the error in R.string.click_here!

Comment: I changed my answer... please replace this to fix error of R.string.click_here
or
add string value to your strings.xml as <string name ="click_here">Click Here</String>